# How to split list to multiple lists that have all the same elements

Tags: java, list

I have the following list of String

```java
["a", "a", "b", "b", "b"]
```

I want to create lists that have elements that repeat themselves more than once, for the previous example that would be

```java
["a", "a"], ["b", "b", "b"]
```

How can I achieve that in java?

EDIT:
elements may not be ordered in primary list.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The community is here to help you on your code, if you don't provide the code you wrote, we cannot help you.

Comment: I do not even know what to try, I do not have any ideas

Comment: `elmts.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity())).values()` you can elaborate the idea

Comment: What about writing a loop, iterating on your input list, and building a result object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity())).values();
```

Comment: values return Collection, you can use `.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());` to return a List

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
private void splitDuplicateList(String[] arr) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String item : arr) {
        if (!map.containsKey(item)) {
            map.put(item, 1);
        } else {
            map.put(item, map.get(item) + 1);
        }
    }
    for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int count = 0; count < (int) entry.getValue(); count++) {
            list.add((String) entry.getKey());
        }
        System.out.println(list.toString());
    }
}
```